# Solidity: TypeError Invalid type. Invalid implicit conversion from type (string storage pointer) to string meory requested

Tags: struct, solidity

I am trying to return values from a struct, different approaches weren`successful

```
struct Briefing {
        string description;
        uint max_influencer;
        uint jobvalue;
        bool achievement;
        }

function getSummary() public view returns (Briefing) {
        return Briefing (
        string, 
        uint,
        uint, 
        bool
        );
```

Comment: Consider changing your title to a plain formatted question. That will give you better attraction to your issue. [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you're working with reference types (such as `struct`), you always need to specify the data location. In this case, it's memory, because you need to load the values to memory first, and then return them from the memory.

Your question doesn't specify if you need to return a new instance of the `struct` or load it from storage, so here's example of both:

```
pragma solidity ^0.8;

contract MyContract {
    struct Briefing {
        string description;
        uint max_influencer;
        uint jobvalue;
        bool achievement;
    }
    
    Briefing summary;

    function getSummaryHardcoded() public view returns (Briefing memory) {
        return Briefing("desc", 1, 1, true);
    }

    function getSummaryStored() public view returns (Briefing memory) {
        return summary;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, it was the second case